# Call parent component method from child in slot

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

Is it possible to call the parent method from a child in a slot? For example:

`parent.component.ts`

```
methodFromParentComponent() {
    console.log('fires...')
}
```

And then something like this:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component (click)="methodFromParentComponent"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Ofcourse that won't work. I tried experimenting with `ngTemplateOutlet`:

```
<parent-component [slotTemplateRef]="slotTemplateRef">
    <ng-template #slotTemplateRef let-methodFromParent>
        <button  (click)="methodFromParent">Navigate</button>
    </ng-template>
</parent-component>
```

The problem is, it fires twice, because the event bubbles up, makes sense. Any directions on what I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works with `ngTemplateOutlet`. Had to story my methods in an object.

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="layoutTemplate; context: { context: templateContext }">
</ng-container>
```

```
<parent-component>
    <ng-template let-context="context">
        <child-component (click)="context.methodFromParentComponent()">
        </child-component>
    </ng-template>
</parent-component>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first code sample could work if you add a [template reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) variable:

```js
<parent-component #parent>
    <child-component (click)="parent.methodFromParentComponent()"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to maintain the context by using `ngTemplateOutlet`. I got it working.